# Cannot download Burger King app because it's not available in my country

Tags: google-play-store

I can't download the Burger King app. It says that this app is not available in my country. I'm based in the UK looking to download Burger King UK.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Just in case there has been changed since then, [the BK UK's official site](https://www.burgerking.co.uk/) now points to this [Burger King app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emn8.mobilem8.nativeapp.bkuk) (`com.emn8.mobilem8.nativeapp.bkuk`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that your Google Play store needs to be registered in the UK. If it isn't registered, do it because it isn't a global app.

Alternatively, try to clear cache and data following these steps:

1. Go to [Settings > Applications > Manage applications > Google app store]
2. Click [clear cache] and [clear data].
3. Open Google Play Store and try to install the app again.

Last, if nothing worked, download the APK of Burger King UK from Google and install it on your phone by activating the developer options on your settings.